# Generate row for month of each year from given datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, common-table-expression

I use the following query to generate row based on table field called 'InsertDate':

```
;WITH listOfMonth(MonthNumber,ContractId )
AS
(
    select 
       DATEPART(month, StartDate) as m,Id as ContractId from tblContract  where  Id = 6674
    union all
    select MonthNumber + 1 as MonthNumber ,ContractId 
    from listOfMonth
    where MonthNumber <  DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
)
select * from listOfMonth
```

For example if `InsertDate` is 4/19/2021 I have below output:

| ID | MonthNumber | ContractId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6674 |
| 2 | 5 | 6674 |
| 3 | 6 | 6674 |
| 4 | 7 | 6674 |
| 5 | 8 | 6674 |
| 6 | 9 | 6674 |

But I also need to generate row based on year so I change query:

```
;WITH listOfMonth(YearNumber,MonthNumber,ContracId)
AS
(
    select 
       DATEPART(Year, StartDate) as YearNumber,DATEPART(month, StartDate) as m,Id as ContracId from tblContract where  Id = 6674
    union all
    select YearNumber, MonthNumber + 1 as MonthNumber ,ContracId
    from listOfMonth
    where MonthNumber <  DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
)
select * from listOfMonth
```

This query generate year column but only for current year of InsertDate,
for example if InsertDate is  4/19/2020 ,it only generate column for 2020 year but I want to generate column for both 2020 and 2021
I use SQL Server 2008 R2
Final output should be like this:

| ID | MonthNumber | ContractId | YearNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 2 | 5 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 3 | 6 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 4 | 7 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 5 | 8 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 6 | 9 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 7 | 10 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 8 | 11 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 9 | 12 | 6674 | 2020 |
| 10 | 1 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 11 | 2 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 12 | 3 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 13 | 4 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 14 | 5 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 15 | 6 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 16 | 7 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 16 | 8 | 6674 | 2021 |
| 16 | 9 | 6674 | 2021 |

Comment: This would also go up to month "13" too; you're just adding +1 to the month's number each time, not actually adding a month.

Comment: Meaningful sample data, and expected results, will help us help you here.

Comment: @DaleK i put code ,not its image;image that you see is result !

Comment: @DaleK ok,sorry about that but its not formatted well

Comment: @DaleK can you show me another question in SO that show tabular data as text?

Comment: @DaleK ok ,id edit post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would represent the month as a *date*:

```
with listOfMonth AS(
      select datefromparts(year(startdate), month(startdate), 1) as yyyymm,
             Id as ContractId
      from tblContract
      where Id = 6674
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, yyyymm), ContractId 
      from listOfMonth
      where yyyymm < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
     )
select *
from listOfMonth
option maxrecursion (0);
```

If you want year and month in separate columns, then do that in the outer query:

```
select year(yyyymm) as year, month(yyyymm) as month
```

Comment: thanks for answer ,does it work on SQL Server 2008 R2??
our production server is based on SQL Server 2008 R2!!!

Comment: my date time is based on persian date(ex:1398/02/29),it give me error Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @amin what would be the persian date equivalent for getdate()?

Comment: @SalmanA there is no equivalent in SQL2008,i create custom function to convert it

Answer (score 1):

Recursive CTE's in SQL Server are a slow way to loop through your data (that's why the limit is set so low, i.e. "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted").  The fast way to generate rows is using either a "numbers table" (a table containing a sequence as rows) or a [function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) (aka "tally function").  This uses a tally function called dbo.fnTally.  A numbers table could be substituted for the tally function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
    Jeff Moden Script on SSC: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

```
select year(calc.dt) YearNumber,
       month(calc.dt) MonthNumber,
       c.ContractId
from (values (cast('20190101' as date), 123),
             (cast('20201201' as date), 456)) c(StartDate, ContractId)
     cross apply dbo.fnTally(0, datediff(month, StartDate, getdate())) fn
     cross apply (values (dateadd(month, fn.n, StartDate))) calc(dt)
order by c.ContractId, YearNumber, MonthNumber;
```

```
YearNumber  MonthNumber ContractId
2019        1           123
2019        2           123
...
2019        12          123
2020        1           123
...
2021        9           123

2020        12          456
2021        1           456
...
2021        9           456
```

Comment: 3 cross-joins is completely ample here, and gives you 4096 months

Comment: The cross join is never created because it's limited by a row goal, i.e. SELECT TOP

Comment: There are performance improvements to tally functions if you restrict the data type of the return value to smallint, int, etc.

Comment: That's not quite right: all the cross-joins do execute, most of them only once. There is some overhead in startup and close-out for each, plus compile cost. I doubt `int` to `smallint` would make any difference on an x86-64 processor, `bigint` might.

Comment: my complete source use 4 CTE each of which add column to final result. i should change my whole script completely

Comment: Yea it's an ongoing topic.  No way 2 billion rows are generated tho.  On other forums this has been thoroughly gone through with IO metrics and different return types etc.  Anyway tally function is mostly for explaining.  In real life we use a physical table

Comment: @AminM with tally approach you don't have to set an arbitrary maximum recursion limit

Comment: @Charlieface multiple tables smallint_n, int_n, bigint_n

Comment: @SteveC I don't understand your code and i don't know how this code fit in my tblContract table ,also this is bad practice that you put static number like 123 in code. I read them from table rows

Comment: Unless you post your code I have no idea either.  My advice is to run the code a bunch of times and comment out different parts to see how it works